# Users activity history

Tags: users

we had some problems in our wordpress web when we changed some issues on the code, and I would like to identify which of the changes made the web crash.

I've tried some plugins as Simple History, but the problem is that you can't get the activity made previously to the installation of the plugin.

Does someone know how could I get the whole activity of the site, even we had no plugins installed?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you looked at the error.log file for indications of what file caused an error? Have you disabled any recent changes, or recent plugins? More info needed...

Answer (score 0):

It's not going to show you previous history *before the plugin was activated*, there's no way to do that as you have to have the plugin activated for it to log and store those.  This is not something done by default in WordPress.

What you need to do instead is to enable WordPress debugging, and then check the logs.

In your `wp-config.php` file, enable debug logging, by adding this:

```
define('WP_DEBUG', true);
define('WP_DEBUG_LOG', true);
define('WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY', true);
```

This will show the errors on screen, set `WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY` to false to prevent showing on screen.

With `WP_DEBUG_LOG` set to true, this will create a file located at `wp-content/debug.log` which you can view to see any errors or warnings from PHP on your site.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I will try this and say something back here.